# Functional Weak Convergence of Maximum Likelihood Estimator

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, limit-theorems

Let $\hat{\theta}_n$ be the Maximum Likelihood Estimator of parameter $\theta$, where $n$ is the sample size. It is well-known that under sufficient regularity conditions, we have the asymptotic normality:
$$
\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta)\Rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2),
$$
where $\sigma^2>0$ is the inverse of the Fisher information.

I wonder if the following Donsker-type functional form of the weak convergence has been established:
$$
\left(t\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}_{\lfloor nt\rfloor }-\theta)\right)_{t\in [0,1]}\Rightarrow \left(\sigma B(t) \right)_{t\in [0,1]},
$$
where $\Rightarrow$ now stands for weak convergence in Skorokhod space $D[0,1]$, and $B(t)$ stands for the standard Brownian motion (Wiener process).

Remark: by modifying the proof of the asymptotic normality, one can easily get the convergence of the finite-dimensional distributions. However, I do not see how to approach the tightness in general (of course it follows from classical results when $\hat{\theta}_n$ is the sample mean).